# Novel, first of series, all I can remember is a girl fighting a ghost on a hill with musical magic

Tags: story-identification, novel

I can specifically recall a particular bit where the girl is much later working in a shop and raises the price on an item, rather than selling it for what it was logged in at. Read some time in the mid 90’s. I recall the cover having the ghost in question and the girl wearing an open vest.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When you say the girl used musical magic, was there a particular instrument?  Or was it singing?  You say the item wasn't sold for "what it was logged in at."  Does that mean this was set in a modern milieu with computerized tills?  How old was the girl, did she have a family?  Did she have a mentor or teacher?

Comment: Fantasy setting, with a large log book containing prices. Singing, rather than an instrument. I think there was a mentor, but I am not certain.

Answer (score 9):

[*The Lark and the Wren*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/511206.The_Lark_and_the_Wren) by Mercedes Lackey, first book of the *Bardic Voices* series.

[image: Front cover of The Lark and the Wren showing Rune fiddling for the Ghost of Skull Hill]

> With the proper schooling young Rune would be one of the greatest bards her world has ever seen. Even if only she knows it. Unfortunately, the daughter of a tavern wench at the Hungry Bear, no matter how talented, doesn't get much in the way of formal training. What she does get is frustrated.
>
> One night, to back up a brag she probably wouldn't have made if she weren't so mad, she went up to play her fiddle for the Ghost of Skull Hill. Everyone knows that no one who has ever gone up Skull Hill at night has come down again. Not alive, anyway.
>
> But when the ghost appears Rune strikes a bargain: if the ghost tires of her playing before morning her life is his; if he is still listening when the sun glints over yonder hill she will have earned both life and a sack of silver. Let the music begin...

I think the scene you're remembering with her marking up prices is in Tonno's shop.

> So whenever she had sold a book lately, she had inflated the price. Scholars would never argue with her, assuming no woman would be so audacious as to cheat a Scholar; their Students never argued with her because she bullied and flattered them the same way she had treated this boy, and with the same effect. And when she added the nonsense about a "discount," they generally kept their mouths shut.

Comment: The Lark and the Wren, Mercedes Lackey. Thank you.

Comment: @Eisenbaer You can click on the checkmark (to the left of the answer, below the score and voting buttons) to mark an answer as correct.

Comment: The first half is promising, but that second half....Oh My God it's bad.